# PHP Check duplicate data and Execute if not

Tags: php

I had a trouble with my PHP Msyql Check data. Source will be see below :

```
$cek_saldo=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query
("SELECT badge_id, bulan, jns_saldo FROM t_saldo WHERE badge_id='$badge_id' AND bulan='Januari' AND jns_saldo='Tabungan Wajib'"));

if ($cek_saldo > 0)
{
    include ("manage_saldo.php");
    echo "<div class='emp'>Saldo already added.</div>";
}
else
{
Save query data.
}
```

I example :
jns_saldo is "Tabungan Wajib"
Badge ID is 165520
Bulan is Januari

So if the example data same with in the table, then give the message "Saldo already added.".
If not, PHP execute to else statement, that's save the data.

Comment: This is not complete source. What is in `manage_saldo.php` ?

Comment: What data type is `badge_id` from you sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo the query that executed. Manually  check this query in the phpmyadmin. so you can found the issue.

```
$query="SELECT badge_id, bulan, jns_saldo FROM t_saldo WHERE badge_id='$badge_id' AND bulan='Januari' AND jns_saldo='Tabungan Wajib'";
    echo $query;
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $cek_saldo=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($cek_saldo > 0)
    {
        include ("manage_saldo.php");
        echo "<div class='emp'>Saldo already added.</div>";
    }
    else
    {
    Save query data.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT badge_id, bulan, jns_saldo FROM t_saldo WHERE badge_id='$badge_id' AND bulan='Januari' AND jns_saldo='Tabungan Wajib'");

if(mysql_num_rows($list) > 0){
    include ("manage_saldo.php");
    echo "<div class='emp'>Saldo already added.</div>";       
}else{
    Save query data.
}
```

or

```
$list = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(badge_id) FROM t_saldo WHERE badge_id='$badge_id' AND bulan='Januari' AND jns_saldo='Tabungan Wajib'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($list)
$cek_saldo = $row[0];

if($cek_saldo  > 0){
        include ("manage_saldo.php");
        echo "<div class='emp'>Saldo already added.</div>";       
    }else{
        Save query data.
    }
```